# Маршруты перекрываются

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть **контроллер**.

```
class About::PagesController < ApplicationController
  add_breadcrumb "Главная", :root_path
  add_breadcrumb "О нас", :about_index_url

  def show
    if partial_name_correct?
      render partial_name
    else
      not_found
    end
  end

  private

  def partial_name
    params[:id].underscore
  end

  def partial_name_correct?
    %w(mission
       otziv
       rukovodstvo
       sostav
       tseli).include? params[:id]
  end
end
```

**Вот маршруты**

```
  resources :videos, only: [:index, :show]
  resources :audios, only: [:index, :show]

  namespace :about do
    resources :pages, only: :show
  end
```

**Вот код для**

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'videos' %>"><a href="<%=videos_path %>">Видео</a></li>
```

Когда я перехожу по адресу `localhost:3000/videos`, то система пишет следующее:

> undefined local variable or method `not_found' for <
>   PagesController:0x007f13d6015ec8 >

У `videos` есть свой контроллер. Я не пойму почему маршруты перекрываются, и он лезет в другой контроллер.

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @videos = Video.all.order(id: :desc).page(params[:page])
  end


  def show
    @videos =  Video.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Маршруты

```
   page GET    /:id(.:format)                      pages#show
       videos GET    /videos(.:format)                   videos#index
        video GET    /videos/:id(.:format)               videos#show
       audios GET    /audios(.:format)                   audios#index
        audio GET    /audios/:id(.:format)               audios#show
   about_page GET    /about/pages/:id(.:format)          about/pages#show
```

Comment: Приведите вывод `rake routes` (или `rails routes`, если Rails 5).

Comment: @D-side добавил маршруты